# Applications icons in JavaFX

Tags: icons, javafx

Using JavaFX 1.2 I am trying to get custom icons on my app and they are being totally ignored.
Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug?

```
Stage {
title: "My App"
width: 1024
height: 768
scene: bind current_scene
iconified:true;
icons:[
    Image { url: "{__DIR__}res/icon16x16.png" },
    Image { url: "{__DIR__}res/icon32x32.png" },
    Image { url: "{__DIR__}res/icon64x64.png" }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Only 123 question tagged "javafx"... why do I get the feeling it's not really taking off?

Comment: Maybe it's so well designed, having a question while developing JavaFX is few and far between ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working. It seems that it was solved with an import statement. Most likely 
    import javafx.scene.image.*; 
but there was a lot happening at the time :)